# Wordpress plug in php issues

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to preface that I am not too fluent in php so i'm trying to understand and build php as i go.

I am attempting to add a custom Slidedeck slider to my website, http://cfsb.org/ . I currently have one in the header, but would like to change it on a per page basis.

```
I currently have: 

    function slidedecktwo_header_home() {
if (is_home()) {
    echo do_shortcode('[SlideDeck2 id=xxx]');
   }
}

add_action('genesis_header', 'slidedecktwo_header_home');
```

But when i try to add something like

```
else if (is_page(PAGE_ID = x)) {
         echo do_shortcode('[SlideDeck2 id=xxx');

}
```

My webpage crashes and I have to delete the code before my website returns. Anyone see some obvious problems?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you missing the ending `]` in your second shortcode, `'[SlideDeck2 id=xxx]'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if what you posted is the actual PHP you tried, but there are definite syntax errors.

Your code should look more like this (I added a random ID passed as an integer to the `is_page()` function):

```
function slidedecktwo_header_home() {
    if ( is_home() ) {
             echo do_shortcode('[SlideDeck2 id=xxx]');
    } elseif ( is_page(42) ) {
            echo do_shortcode('[SlideDeck2 id=xxx]');
    }
}

add_action('genesis_header', 'slidedecktwo_header_home');
```

In your snippet, you had `is_page( PAGE_ID = x )` and your shortcode snippet wasn't closed with a closing bracket `]`

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't copy and paste my actual code as I was waiting for my website to come back up. The code on the website did. Not contain a syntax error. I checked it in an IDE prior to ftping it into the site.

Comment: @Robert, please add real code to your question, so people won't waste time answering to what they *imagine* your problem to be..

Comment: @RobertPerez Yes, please post your real code. I can update my answer based on what you have.

Comment: @disinfor, THANK YOU! I added the code and added the correct page name and now the slidedecks are different on every page just like i wanted. Appreciate you very much!

Also, apologies, my website was crashed and after fixing it, it would not restore. So i was working off memory as i waited for the FTP pushed page to restore my website.

Comment: @RobertPerez You are welcome! I'm glad it's working for you.